# Globally Include Types in SvelteKit Project

Tags: typescript, svelte, tsconfig, sveltekit

*SvelteKit v1.0.0-next.354*

In all my stores, components, and APIs, I have to manually `import` my types in order to use them in order to prevent TypeScript errors in VS Code:

```
import type { MyType } from '$lib/types`
```

I tried putting my class inside `app.d.ts`, but that didn't work.

```
declare namespace App{
  export class Aircraft{
    ...
  }
}
```

This gets pretty cumbersome to do across a project that is getting quite large with dozens of files.

Is there some way to globally include all my types in one place so that they are available in any file across my project? I'm very new to TypeScript and am not sure how this works.

Comment: "that didn't work" is too unspecific. You should show the code you used when trying to access the type and the errors you got. Type declaration files should be discovered pretty much anywhere in the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a `namespace` you have to use the type with said namespace as a prefix, so something like:

```js
const a: App.Aircraft = { ... };
```

If you do not want that, you should declare the type directly:

```js
declare class Aircraft {
  ...
}
```

Then you can just use:

```js
const a: Aircraft = { ... };
```

Note that this only makes the type definitions available, not the type implementation. As you declared this as `class` rather than `interface`, this suggests that this type can be constructed with `new`. Only having the type in scope will *not* allow that.